# Changing data in every document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on an application that has messages and I want to store all the messages. But my problem is the message has a from first name and last name which could change. So if for example my JSON was

```
{
    "subject": "Hello!",
    "message": "Hello there",
    "from": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "firstname": "George",
        "lastname": "Lastgeorge"
    }
}
```

The user could potentially change their last name or even first name. Which would require basically looping over every record in elasticsearch and updating everyone with the user_id.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you should use parent mapping. 
Keep the user info as parent with userID as key.

```
/index/userinfo/userID
    {
       "name" : "George",
       "last" : "Lastgeorge"
    }
```

Next , you need to maintain each chat as a child document and map the parent to the userindo type.
This way , whenever you want to make some change to the user information , simply make the change in userInfo type.

With this feature intact , you can search your logs based on user information , or search users based on chat records.

Link - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html